# Aligned graphs in 12.1?

Tags: plotting, graphics

Yesterday while reading about new features in 12.1 I recall reading about the capability to produce columns, rows or grids of plots with shared axes. For example, to output two plots, one above the other, with each having a y-axis with labels and ticks, but sharing a single x-axis at the bottom of the bottom plot. I know about GraphicsGrid, but I don't think that was it. The two plots need to be aligned.

Now I want to use it, but I've looked everywhere for hours and can't find anything about it in the what's new releases or the documentation.

Was I dreaming? Does anyone know where to find this?

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLayout.html

Comment: @QuantumDot sorry, i'm confused. what does that link have to do with the question?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform You have to look at examples in Scope.  But I think it is limited to only a few plotting functions.

Comment: Thanks, @QuantumDot. But that's not it. I really want to graphs aligned -- not stacked..

Comment: Brett Champion talks about this at the [WTC 2019](https://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?c=467&p=4&v=2893&) , time= 9 minutes. I'm surprised by a strong limitation B. Champion mentions at time=~10 : the Y axes are necessarily the same.

Comment: Take a look at PlotGrid: https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlotGrid

Comment: Thanks @andre314 -- I'm afraid that is it. I tried it and Plot does not have PlotLayout as an option. Even if it did, my purpose is to allow a visual comparison of curves having the same x-axis but very different scaling on the y-axes. So this would not work anyway.

Comment: And Thanks, Gustavo. PlotGrid does indeed do what I want. And thanks to Lukas Lang who wrote it.